# Service about to stop - detect the cause

Tags: windows, winapi, service

In a Windows service, my Service Control Handler receives a `SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP` command. I would like to determine the reason for this command; specifically, I need to know whether the STOP was requested because a depended-upon service ("*master*") is stopping or because of any other reason. The reason is, if my service stopped because the user requested a stop or because Windows is shutting down or any other similar reason, I don't need to do anything, but if my service is stopping because *master* is stopping, I need to make sure I restart my service when *master* restarts.

Unfortunately, I don't really see any source of this information - `RegisterServiceCtrlHandlerEx` will let me provide a handler which can get some details behind the control event, but there doesn't seem to be a notification that I can use. But maybe there's some other way, e.g. getting the info through the Session Manager or something.

Comment: If your service needs to start when *master* starts, mark your service as a dependency of *master*.

Comment: I don't think creating a cyclic dependency is the solution.

Comment: There is no indication in the question that would cause this procedure to introduce a cyclic dependency. This is starting to sound like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info). What problem are you ultimately trying to solve?

Comment: I am trying to do precisely what is written in the question: decide whether my service is stopping because its dependency is stopping or for any other reason. If it is the former case, I will then wait for the dependency to restart and then restart my service. If it is the latter case, then I won't be doing anything at all.

Comment: @IInspectable the OP clearly stated that their service has a dependency on "master". So making "master" have a dependency on their service would be circular.

Comment: @rem: If that's how the system is built, then there *is* a circular dependency, no matter how you approach it. Which makes me wonder how that system ever gets off the ground to begin with. This sounds like *master* and this other service switch roles somewhere during their lifetimes, and that inversion of roles needs to be addressed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In a Windows service, my Service Control Handler receives a `SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP` command. I would like to determine the reason for this command

Sorry, but the SCM does not provide that information to services.

> specifically, I need to know whether the STOP was requested because a depended-upon service ("master") is stopping or because of any other reason.

There is no way for your service to determine that.

> The reason is, if my service stopped because the user requested a stop or because Windows is shutting down or any other similar reason, I don't need to do anything

Detecting Windows shutting down is easy - your service can request to receive `SERVICE_CONTROL_PRESHUTDOWN` and `SERVICE_CONTROL_SHUTDOWN` events. For any other stop reason, it will only receive `SERVICE_CONTROL_STOP` with no explanation as to why.

> if my service is stopping because master is stopping, I need to make sure I restart my service when master restarts.

There are two possible ways to handle that:

- run a separate process that monitors the status of "master", either by regularly polling [`QueryServiceStatus()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsvc/nf-winsvc-queryservicestatus) or by using [`NotifyServiceStatusChange()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsvc/nf-winsvc-notifyservicestatuschangew), and have it start your service when it detects "master" stop and restart.
- if "master" logs events in the system log via an ETW provider, you can use [`ChangeServiceConfig2(SERVICE_CONFIG_TRIGGER_INFO)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsvc/nf-winsvc-changeserviceconfig2w) to register a trigger action that starts your service when a particular event is logged.

> Unfortunately, I don't really see any source of this information - `RegisterServiceCtrlHandlerEx` will let me provide a handler which can get some details behind the control event, but there doesn't seem to be a notification that I can use.

Correct, because there isn't one.

Comment: Thanks. I was afraid that was the case.